# WKWebView appears above my navigationbar and tabbar

Tags: wkwebview, navigationbar, tabbar

I have a viewcontroller that will include a WKWebView. My viewcontroller is inside both a navigationcontroller and tabbarcontroller. The WKWebView appears over both of these, hiding the tabs (on the bottom), and the title and back button (on the top), and they only appear when you scroll up or down. How do I fix this.

[image: This is what it looks like]

[image: This is what it should look like in the navigation bar]

[image: This is what is should look like in the tab bar]

Answer (score 0):

Found it. Changed the webview's scrollview backgroundColor.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).